# check if user touching screen now (JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

can I check if user touching the screen in some time point?
(the time between touchstart and touchend)
something like:

```
$(el).is(":hover") //exist
$(window).is(":touch")
```

must I create something from scratch ? (using touchstart and touchend)

Comment: Probably. You can just set a flag when `touchstart` is triggered.

Answer (score 1):

now I figured out that it's very simple:

```
var ScreenTouchedNow = false;
document.body.addEventListener('touchstart', function(){ScreenTouchedNow=true} );
document.body.addEventListener('touchend', function(){ScreenTouchedNow=false} );

...
if (ScreenTouchedNow) ...
```

Comment: Your code seems to be incomplete. It has syntax errors.

Comment: @Felix Kling: fixed (in the answer). was found by firefox immediately of course.

Comment: It's still incorrect though. `addEventListener` expects a **function**, but you are passing a Boolean. The assignments are actually executed immediately, not when the event occurs.